# ClaimsAuthenticationManager is not invoked

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm facing a weird issue with the WIF ClaimsAuthenticationManager. I have registered the custom implementatin of the ClaimsAuthenticationManager in the web.config file:

```
<identityConfiguration>
  <claimsAuthenticationManager type="<namespace>.CustomClaimsTransformer,<assembly>" />
  <claimsAuthorizationManager type="<namespace>.CustomAuthorisationManager,<assembly>" />
....
```

When i run the application in the IISExpress the authenticate method of the ClaimsAuthenticationManager gets invoked. However, it's not being invoked ever since i deployed the application on IIS 7.5.

Is there any configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: Hi @ppoliani, which authentication type were you using (i.e., Windows, Forms, etc)? Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

In the system.webserver part of your web.config do you have the ClaimsAuthorizationModule set,

eg

```
<add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Answer (score 2):

For .NET 4.5 you have to add this:

```
<add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Comment: The ClaimsAuthorizationModule controls the ClaimsAuthenticationManager being called?  I have this entry, and my custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager which I've specified in the system.identityModel section isn't getting called.

Answer (score 2):

ClaimsAuthenticationManager is not invoked automatically. One needs a plumbing code for that unless they are using WS-Federation.

You can do it in an PostAuthenticateRequest event handler for the HttpApplication.

A good example is located in the http://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45 project. Search for ClaimsAuthenticationHttpModule.cs which invokes it.